# Any-angle routing in Altium?

Tags: altium, routing, eda

I have a design with a very thin and curvy board shape, so any-angle routing is absolutely required.

My favorite EDA software is Altium, so right now I have only two options, both bad, for how to route any-angle:

1. Every time I want to change routes, export the design to another program that does allow any-angle routing, make the changes, and then import back to Altium
2. Painstakingly change the x1,y1 x2,y2 values of every individual track segment using the "Properties" popup window

Clearly Altium can represent any-angle tracks just fine (since option 2 does work), there just isn't any way to use the standard mouse controls to do it!

Is there any way to configure Altium or use a plugin so that the mouse controls can freely change the x1,y1 x2,y2 of tracks without snapping to 45 degree angles?

Comment: Recent versions of Altium allow any-angle-routing. While routing, just click Shift+Space until the routing mode changes to any-angle. I'm pretty sure this has been supported at least as long as the program has been called "Altium".

Comment: Indeed, pressing Shift+Space several times while in Interactive Routing mode did the trick! Thanks a million! If you make that comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Follow-up question: Is there a way to modify already existing tracks in an any-angle way? (Other than deleting and remaking them?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recent versions of Altium allow any-angle-routing. While routing, just click Shift+Space until the routing mode changes to any-angle. I'm pretty sure this has been supported at least as long as the program has been called "Altium".

> Is there a way to modify already existing tracks in an any-angle way? (Other than deleting and remaking them?)

I'm not sure if you have to be in a certain mode or something, but usually if I just click-and-hold the endpoint of a trace segment, it will let me move the end without constraining the trace direction.

Comment: You'll have my eternal gratitude if you can check what mode you're in that lets you drag the trace endpoint in the way you describe. For me, when I drag a trace endpoint, it snaps to 45 degree angles.

Comment: I may have stumbled upon the answer: Each track seems to somehow "remember" whether it was created using the any-angle mode or not. If I drag a track that was created using any-angle, then I can drag the endpoints freely. But if I drag a track that was imported from another program, then it has the 45 degree snap behavior. Do you know if there is any way to change this hidden property of an already-created track to allow it to be edited in the any-angle way?

Comment: I think you can Shift-Space while dragging a track end. But I'm not at work to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the 'Interactive Routing' configuration menu (Tools/Preferences/Interactive Routing) you'll find the options related to the track angle, such as 'Preserve Angle When Dragging' and  'Restrict to 90/45'. Try them!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this question too.
And I found something similar to what I was looking for.

Hold "Alt" befor clicking the endpoint!

It's so simple, but I have not seen this advice anywhere. I stumbled upon it by poking (by pushing every button and try to find it anywise).

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.