# Altium: routing at 30, 120, 210 and 300 degrees

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, routing

On my board, I need to route a certain area with standard 45° and 90° angles and another area with 30° and 120° angles.

How can I achieve this? (Any angle mode is not satisfying.)

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the X,Y coordinate and specify the nodes directly?

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/79350/2028

Answer (score 3):

As of Altium 22.10.1, there is no support for routing at *specific* angles other than 0/45/90 and rotations thereof. Using **Any Angle** routing mode allows you to place traces at an arbitrary angle, but they are not constrained to a specific angle or set of angles.

When I need to route a section of a board at an angle not supported natively, I typically will try to do as much as possible using the default angles (0/45/90), then rotate the entire section. For example, an antenna feed line with its associated filter components is much easier to lay out horizontally or vertically, then rotate to the desired angle and position as needed. Some editing of traces is usually required where they meet with those of another angle regime.

Comment: Great answer, especially since what  OP wants can be accomplished by a single 30° rotation after snapping to the usual 0/45/90/180/270 angles.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this would be to create another [local grid](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-grids-system). If doing this for a lot of traces you could offset one square grid by 30 deg and it should be orthogonal to 120deg. Then snap to that grid. You can do this by creating a new grid, then say the rotation setting to 30deg

Comment: This is accomplished using the "Rotation" setting for the new local grid. I would call this a non-hacky solution, i.e., a good solution.

Comment: I like this option for providing an excellent snap-to framework for the any-angle routing. It doesn't, however, affect the behavior of the 45-degree corner style, so making turns within a trace (from 30 to 120 degrees, for example) may require a bit of attention.

Answer (score 1):

PITA/hacky, but maybe handy from time to time.

Place a trace.  Rotate it 30 degrees (M, O).  Drag the end: this may give any-angle move (without holding ALT), in which case cancel.  Usually once the other end is overlapping another trace, it will give fixed angle stretching; use this to set desired length, or get something close.  Or slice tracks (E, K) to get shorter pieces.

Rubber-stamp a few copies on the route.  They will inherit the touched net, and split automatically at intersections.  Delete the stubs to get a clean angled corner.  The tracks can be dragged around as usual, keeping their angle.  Avoid using the corner-drag / create new corners feature, which will snap everything to 45° again.

This is also a useful way to find geometric intersections when drawing.  Arcs will also cut automatically, when on a copper layer and assigned a net.